# How do you run Python within Sublime?

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, sublimetext

I have python 3 installed with Jupyter and Anaconda environment. I want to have Python installed on its own with Sublime Text to access it. I succeeded downloading Python and can access it from CMD, but I am unable to make it run in Sublime Text. I got the instructions from a book on Python but it is still not working. Anyone could help on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By pressing Ctrl + B , Sublime 3 will run the python code inside the integrated console (provided you have saved the file with .py file extension)

For more information/clarification, please visit:
[https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-run-code-in-sublime-text/#:~:text=By%20pressing%20Ctrl%20%2B%20B%20%2C%20Sublime,py%20file%20extension](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-run-code-in-sublime-text/#:%7E:text=By%20pressing%20Ctrl%20%2B%20B%20%2C%20Sublime,py%20file%20extension)).]